# How to repair fedora after failed update

Tags: linux, fedora

I had to cancel my dnf update in between of storm. Now I can't boot into fedora, shows a black screen or blinking screen. I asked for help on fedora discord, but they couldn't find a solution. Im planning to reinstall it now. Is there any way to repair the os install with a live USB or something.

I installed fedora with dual boot alongside windows 10. I had amd radeon gpu and amd ryzen 5 cpu. Any help would be appreciated/
PS: I'm noob to linux please bare with me

Comment: You could try to login on a text console (ctrl + alt +f2 and login with your user. Then try to continue the update process: `sudo dnf upgrade`)

Answer (score 0):

1. press this keys '''Ctrl + Alt + F2''' you will see a screen asking for username and password. if not try pressing the same keys but change from F2 to F3 and try it.
2. after entering your username and password try this GUI command '''startx'''.
3. Now you should be able to use your OS. if this doesn't work then it is better to reinstall it.